# Prove the following is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Prove f is a ring homomorphism

$ f: \Bbb{R}[X] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}[X]/ \langle X ^4 \rangle, \sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i \rightarrow \overline  {\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^{2i}}  $

I need some tips on this one please.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Composition of Ring homomorphisms is a Ring homomorphism.Can you see $f$ as composition of two ring homomorphisms?

Comment: No i dont see it :C ...

Comment: @ggok: Instead of saying  "No i dont see it" at once,IMO its better to think for sometime.

Comment: yes i know i was just frustrated ...

Comment: Hint: $p(X) \to p(X^2)$ is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb R[X] \to \mathbb R[X]$.Can you take it from here?